# Custom validation of WooCommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

I would like add my own regular expression for validating the phone number. In my `class-wc-validation.php` I have changed the regular expression to my requirement.

```
public static function is_phone( $phone ) {
    //if ( strlen( trim( preg_replace( '/[\s\#0-9_\-\+\(\)]/', '', $phone ) ) ) > 0 )
    if ( strlen( trim( preg_replace( '/^[6789]\d{9}$/', '', $phone ) ) ) > 0 )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

But the validation is not happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 26):

Was facing the same issue and followed what others had said here, but Woocommerce only sets the errors on validation after `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook.

But, in the latest Woocommerce 3.0 (not sure if this is in the 2.x version), we can use the `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` hook and then look into the `$data` param if you are using the standard checkout fields or use `$_POST` if you have custom fields that aren't added in the standard Woocommerce way. An example of the code is:

```
public function validate($data,$errors) { 
    // Do your data processing here and in case of an 
    // error add it to the errors array like:
        $errors->add( 'validation', __( 'Please input that correctly.' ));
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate',10,2);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 21):

I have not seen your code that hooks these up to the woocommerce checkout flow.
please check their documentation on

`woocommerce_checkout_process` and `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`

But in your case, I highly suggest that you hook it up on `woocommerce_checkout_process`

so put these codes below on your functions.php on your theme, or you create your own woocommerce plugins, and put it in the bootstrap code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'is_phone');

function is_phone() { 
    $phone_number = $_POST['---your-phone-field-name---'];
    // your function's body above, and if error, call this wc_add_notice
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Your phone number is wrong.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> **You should not edit plugin files**, because if you update plugin all the
>   customization will be lost, rather you can use hook to achieve your
>   goal. You can use using [`woocommerce_checkout_process`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-5) hook to do
>   this.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wh_phoneValidateCheckoutFields');

function wh_phoneValidateCheckoutFields() {
    $billing_phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_phone');

    if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/^[6789]\d{9}$/', '', $billing_phone))) > 0) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Invalid <strong>Phone Number</strong>, please check your input.'), 'error');
    }
}
```

*Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin PHP files.*

Please Note: *By default WooCommerce use `billing_phone` field to take phone number, but if you have customized it then you can replace `billing_phone` with your field name.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your question you're saying that validation rule is not working and I guess it's written in a wrong way. You can test it in online with regexp tools, e.g. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) or others.

To answer more general on this topic, changing validation rules safely can be done this way:

Make a copy of `class-wc-validation.php` to your theme directory in `your_theme_path/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-validation.php` and make customization to the validation rules.

Then you should make a validation rule for the phone filed in `checkout.js` otherwise your field always will have green border despite it's invalid.

So my solution was to add custom regular expression validator to `checkout.js` about line 192:

```
    if ( $parent.is( '.validate-phone' ) ) {
            if ( $this.val() ) {

                var pattern = new RegExp(/^([0-9\s\/\+\-\#\_\(\)]*)$/);

                if ( ! pattern.test( $this.val()  ) ) {
                    $parent.removeClass( 'woocommerce-validated' ).addClass( 'woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-phone' );
                    validated = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

And include your customized .js file (in `functions.php`)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_checkoutjs_enqueue_scripts', 100 );

function gv_checkoutjs_enqueue_scripts() {

if ( is_checkout() ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'wc-checkout' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-checkout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modified_checkout.js', array( 'jquery', 'woocommerce', 'wc-country-select', 'wc-address-i18n' ) );
}}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should not override a core file, this is a bad idea, even more doing it in an essential plugin for your store.