# Allow only letter on specific Woocommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Trying to force Letters only (possibly also with non-English characters) in Woocommerce checkout field, First Name.
we often have older customers so we need to control user input and prevent errors in advance.

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I'm aware of the Custom Validation thread [Custom validation of WooCommerce checkout fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603144/custom-validation-of-woocommerce-checkout-fields)
... but it feels like this should be far simpler and specific solve?

Used Businessbloomers' code for forcing numbers only in Post Code field (works fine).
SOURCE: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-change-input-type-checkout-fields/

```
function bbloomer_change_checkout_field_input_type() {
echo "<script>document.getElementById('billing_postcode').type = 'number'; 
</script>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_change_checkout_field_input_type');
```

For Fname I changed type input to 'letter'.. but no result (still able to input numbers).
Swapped 'type' for 'pattern', as below, but no luck.

```
function JBC_Force_letters_in_fname_field() {
echo "<script>document.getElementById('billing_first_name').pattern='[A- Za-z]';</script>";

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'JBC_Force_letters_in_fname_field');
```

- Expecting: David
- Getting/Allowing: Dav1D3

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I think it would be easier to use jquery validation for this purpose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will remove numeric characters and some punctuation characters from billing and shipping first name and last name checkout fields and will handle also the postcode:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_field_name_validator_script');
function checkout_field_name_validator_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) return;
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var b = '#billing_',    s = '#shipping_',   f = 'first_',   l = 'last_',
            n = 'name',         p = 'postcode',     c = ',';

        // Postcode fields
        $(b+p+c+s+p).bind('keyup blur',function(){
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/,''));
        });

        // First and Last name fields
        $(b+f+n+c+b+l+n+c+s+f+n+c+s+l+n).bind('keyup blur',function(){
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[0-9.,;:?!]+/,''));
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Perfect! Used code Snippets, set to work  everywhere, works perfect. Thank  you :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Help me please, in my shipping field (woocomerce) clients write in  Hebrew, how allow only latin letter? I found function: public function 

validateLatin($string) {
    $result = false;
 
    if (preg_match("/^[\w\d\s.,-]*$/", $string)) {
        $result = true;
    }
 
    return $result;
}

but how use in your code?  Thanks

Comment: @user3331122 Sorry I can't help on that subject…